# Remove duplicate rows displayed in pivot

Tags: sql, t-sql, pivot

Basically, I have created a pivot query wherein it will display the total_work_hours per each costcode for each employee.

This is my desired output:

```
employeeno  8322.170    10184.2648    8321.169    10184.2649 <- costcodes
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
080418         10.00          1.50        NULL          NULL
080441          6.50          NULL        1.00          3.00
```

but this is the result of my query:

```
employeeno  8322.170    10184.2648    8321.169    10184.2649 <- costcodes
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
080418         10.00          NULL        NULL          NULL
080418          NULL          1.50        NULL          NULL
080441          NULL          NULL        1.00          NULL
080441          6.50          NULL        NULL          NULL
080441          NULL          NULL        NULL          3.00
```

This is the result of my inner query:

```
      employeeno    costcoding  hour_per_costcode        
      --------------------------------------------------
      PH080418   8322.170       10.00
      PH080418   10184.2648     1.50
      PH080441   8321.169       1.00
      PH080441   8322.170       6.50
      PH080441   10184.2649     3.00
```

This is my query:

```sql
WITH PivotData AS  
    (SELECT wa.id,wa.sitecode, wa.companycode, wa.startdate, wa.enddate,  
            wa.description, wa.ratetypeid, wa_details.employeeno,  
            CAST(wa_details.costcode AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '.' +
            CAST(wa_details.subcostcode AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) costcoding ,
            wa_details.subcostcode, wa_details.hrswork [hour_per_costcode],  
            view_ttl_hours.ttl_work_hrs 
       FROM workallocation wa  
      INNER JOIN workallocation_details wa_details 
         ON wa.id = wa_details.workallocationid   
      INNER JOIN 
            (SELECT SUM(ttl_work_hrs) ttl_work_hrs, employee_id 
               FROM vwu_SUM_TIMESHEET_DAILY  
              WHERE TKSDATE BETWEEN '02-09-2012' AND '02-09-2012' 
              GROUP BY employee_id
            ) view_ttl_hours 
         ON wa_details.employeeno=view_ttl_hours.employee_id  WHERE wa.id=99
    )
SELECT employeeno, [8322.170], [10184.2648], [8321.169], [10184.2649]
  FROM PivotData   
 PIVOT (MAX([hour_per_costcode])          
        FOR costcoding         
         IN ([8322.170], [10184.2648], [8321.169], [10184.2649])
        ) AS PivotResult  
 ORDER BY employeeno;
```

My question is how will I be able to unite the value for my multiple rows so that my desire output will be achieve? I also try the cross tab query but the result is also the same.

I need some guidance on how to solve this; can you help?

Comment: If you change your select in the last query to `SELECT *` is should be pretty obvious what is causing the issue. The other recommendation I can give is to eliminate everything from PivotData that is not directly used by the pivot.

Comment: @cadrell0 - thanks for the reply. I already notice that the duplicate long time ago but my details table consist of employeeno,costcode,subcostcode and hrswork. All of them is Unique key.

Comment: Base on @cadrell0's comment. How about add another query in `with` clause(like `PivotData2 as (select employeeno, [8322.170], [10184.2648]... from PivotData)`), then change the last query to `SELECT * ... FROM PivotData2`.

Comment: @evanc3 i already tried and the result is the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the columns you don't need from the CTE. Something like this should work for you.

```
WITH PivotData AS  
    (SELECT wa_details.employeeno,  
            CAST(wa_details.costcode AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '.' +
            CAST(wa_details.subcostcode AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) costcoding ,
            wa_details.subcostcode, wa_details.hrswork [hour_per_costcode]
       FROM workallocation wa  
      INNER JOIN workallocation_details wa_details 
         ON wa.id = wa_details.workallocationid   
      INNER JOIN 
            (SELECT SUM(ttl_work_hrs) ttl_work_hrs, employee_id 
               FROM vwu_SUM_TIMESHEET_DAILY  
              WHERE TKSDATE BETWEEN '02-09-2012' AND '02-09-2012' 
              GROUP BY employee_id
            ) view_ttl_hours 
         ON wa_details.employeeno=view_ttl_hours.employee_id  WHERE wa.id=99
    )
SELECT employeeno, [8322.170], [10184.2648], [8321.169], [10184.2649]
  FROM PivotData   
 PIVOT (MAX([hour_per_costcode])          
        FOR costcoding         
         IN ([8322.170], [10184.2648], [8321.169], [10184.2649])
        ) AS PivotResult  
 ORDER BY employeeno;
```

Above query with your data:

```
WITH PivotData AS  
    (select 'PH080418' as employeeno,   8322.170 as costcoding, 10.00 as hour_per_costcode union all
     select 'PH080418', 10184.2648, 1.50 union all
     select 'PH080441', 8321.169,   1.00 union all
     select 'PH080441', 8322.170,   6.50 union all
     select 'PH080441', 10184.2649, 3.00
    )
SELECT employeeno, [8322.170], [10184.2648], [8321.169], [10184.2649]
  FROM PivotData   
 PIVOT (MAX([hour_per_costcode])          
        FOR costcoding         
         IN ([8322.170], [10184.2648], [8321.169], [10184.2649])
        ) AS PivotResult  
 ORDER BY employeeno;
```

Result:

```
employeeno 8322.170   10184.2648   8321.169   10184.2649
---------- ---------- ------------ ---------- -----------
PH080418   10.00      1.50         NULL       NULL
PH080441   6.50       NULL         1.00       3.00
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply. I think no one understand my problem. I want my rows to be unique. Please read my description. Thanks!

Comment: @user1378857 Did you try the query I provided to you? What was the output?

Comment: yes i tried the query you gave to me. The result is the same with my query. The rows are not unique.

Comment: @user1378857 Is the output the same as with your query?

Comment: @user1378857 Please post the output of the query in the CTE `PivotDate` to your question.

Comment: employeeno 8322.170 10184.2648  8321.169 10184.2649
================================================================== PH080418 10.00 NULL NULL NULL
PH080418 NULL 1.50 NULL NULL
PH080441 NULL NULL 1.00 NULL
PH080441 6.50 NULL NULL NULL
PH080441 NULL NULL NULL 3.00

Comment: i'm sorry im just new here i don't know how to format my comment. But if you can take a look at my question. The result and my desire output is there. Thank you!

Comment: @user1378857 the output for the query **in the CTE** should have three columns `emoployeeno, costcoding, hour_per_costcode`. Post the output from that query. Not the output from the entire query and post it to your question where you can format the output.

Comment: i just posted the result of my inner query.

Comment: @user1378857 I have updated my answer with a version that uses your data and the output **is** what you want.

Comment: thank you! UNION ALL is the answer. I will just use this for my dynamic query. Thanks again!

Comment: @user1378857 - What? `union all` has nothing to do with your query. I just used `union all` to show you how the query works with your data. What makes this query work is the **removal of extra columns** in the CTE, nothing else.

Comment: yes, yes i notice it. :D Thank you for making me realize my fault. I should have remove unnecessary columns. Thank you! You help me with this problem.